# How to correctly specify the path to chromedriver in pythonanywhere project

Tags: python, selenium, path, pythonanywhere, undetected-chromedriver

I want to specify the path to a file in a python project on the pythonanywhere site. Unfortunately, I am getting an error. Here are pictures of the folder and console

Code:

```
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, driver_executable_path="/user/KraKoff/files/home/KraKoff/chromedriver.exe")
```

[image: Console]

[image: Folder]

Comment: Isn't that file just in `/home/KraKoff/chromedriver.exe`? There's nothing in the console that indicates that `/user/KraKoff/files` is part of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not specify the chromedriver path on PythonAnywhere. It is not necessary.

Comment: Now it is _Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:60291
from chrome not reachable_ error...

Answer (score 1):

You are using [pythonanywhere](/questions/tagged/pythonanywhere)

[image: pythonanywhere]

So you need to download and use the *ChromeDriver* executable of [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) type instead of the [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) type and you need to pass the *absolute path* without the extension i.e. `.exe`.

---

### Solution

Your effective line of code will be:

```
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, driver_executable_path="/user/KraKoff/files/home/KraKoff/chromedriver")
```

Comment: Downloaded linux version.
With `/user/KraKoff/files/home/KraKoff/chromedriver` path the error stays the same.
Tried `/home/KraKoff/chromedriver` and now and now the error is this:

_Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home_

Added print(uc.Patcher.data_path) in code and aslo in console is _PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/KraKoff/chromedriver'_

Comment: Hi! facing the same problem. Have you managed to resolve the permission issue?